# disable spinner based another spinner android

Tags: android, android-spinner

how to disable a spinner based on another spinner. For sample, when I choose first spinner value is "Yes" then the second spinner is enable also when I choose first spinner value is "No" then the second spinner is disable.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be a little more clear and maybe show an example of what your problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    final Spinner sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final Spinner sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    ArrayAdapter<String> data = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, first);
    ArrayAdapter<String> data2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, second);

    sp1.setAdapter(data);
    sp2.setAdapter(data2);
    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            String text = sp1.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if (text.equals("No")) {
                sp2.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                sp2.setEnabled(true);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but it's still not working. I've tried both solution. Any suggestion?